# if not exists insert in MySql

Tags: mysql, insert

This is MS SQL code

```
    if not exists (select PId from Person
             where Name = 'Name1' and Surname = 'Surname1')
    INSERT INTO [someDb].[dbo].[Person] 
        ([Name] ,[Surname])
    VALUES
        ('Name1' ,'Surname1')
```

can you please help me to write ekvivalent code in for my sql

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a unique index on (name,surname), you can use INSERT IGNORE:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `someDb`.`Person` 
        (`Name` ,`Surname`)
    VALUES
        ('Name1' ,'Surname1')
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL <s>it's usually done</s> I was usually doing it before I saw the other answer with

```
INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=ID;
```

In your case it would require a UNIQUE index on (Name,Surname) columns

Comment: what does this do? I have tried it and it inserts new row every time

Comment: on duplicate triggers when you have a non-unique value inserted into a field that must contain a unique value (either a primary key or a unique index: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html)