# PHP Prepared Statement insert or update If row exists

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I have been searching for a fix for my code below. I have searched many similar post in stackoverflow but didn't get a work around.

What I'm trying to establish is that, I want to check a query and if row exist I need to use UPDATE statement else INSERT statement. I have established this many time but without the prepared statement. Now that I'm modifying many of my previous codes with the prepared statements. Below is my code.

```
<?php

include'../db.php';

$exercise_days=$_POST['edays'];
$id=$_POST['id'];

if ($exercise_days!='' && is_numeric($exercise_days)) 
{
    $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * from exercisetable where id=?");
    $query->bind_param('s', $id);
    /* execute query */
    $query->execute();
    /* store result */
    $query->store_result();
    $query->bind_result($rowcheck);
    $query->fetch();
    if ($rowcheck)
    {
        $e_update=$db1->prepare("UPDATE exercisetable SET exercise_days=? WHERE id=?");
        $e_update->bind_param('ss', $exercise_days, $id);
        $e_update->execute();
        if($e_update){
        $message='Exercise Days Updated';
        $success='Success';
        echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'success'=>$success));
        }
        $e_update->close();

    } else {
        $e_insert=$db1->prepare("INSERT INTO exercisetable (`id`, `exercise_days`) VALUES (?,?)");
        $e_insert->bind_param('ss', $id, $exercise_days);
        $e_insert->execute();
        if($e_insert){
        $message='Exercise Days Inserted';
        $success='Success';
        echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'success'=>$success));
        }
        $e_insert->close();

    }
}

else  
{
    $message='Exercise Days Can Only Be Numbers';
    $success='Error';
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'success'=>$success));
} 
 ?>
```

Executing the above code always go into else statement where it goes to INSERT even though row exists. What I want is UPDATE if row Exists and INSERT if else. Any help appreciated.

Comment: investigate `on duplicate key` syntax to perform the update perhaps ~ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if not exists insert in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674849/if-not-exists-insert-in-mysql)

Comment: You can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008191/mysqli-insert-but-only-if-not-a-duplicate)

Comment: @Martin Dimitrov , I'm very well aware to perform this without prepared statement. What I'm trying is using prepared statement. Your link take me back to non-prepared statement. Thanks anyway

Comment: @RamRaider , do I need to alter mysql columns as unique

Comment: @theveil the first link will work with a prepared statement. This is a built in functionality.

Comment: @Martin Dimitrov the mentioned if not exists insert do not give option to update existing, so I chose on duplicate key. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @RamRaider for the hint and suggestion. I'm posting the solution that worked for me, if in case anyone would require an instant reference.

Few edits that were done to MySql column prior to change in my original PHP code were that I altered my column to UNIQUE.

```
<?php

include'../db.php';

$exercise_days=$_POST['exercise_days'];
$id=$_POST['id'];

if ($exercise_days!='' && is_numeric($exercise_days))  
{
        $query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO exercisetable (`id`, `exercise_days`) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE exercise_days =?");
        $query->bind_param('sss', $id, $exercise_days, $exercise_days);
        $query->execute();
        if($query){
        $message='Exercise Days Inserted';
        $success='Success';
        echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'success'=>$success));
        }
        $query->close();
}

else
{
    $message='Excercise Days Can Only Be Numbers';
    $success='Error';
    echo json_encode(array('message'=>$message,'success'=>$success));
} 
 ?>
```

Comment: Instead of duplicating bound params, you can alter your SQL's UPDATE code to use `VALUES`: ``$query=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO exercisetable (`id`, `exercise_days`) VALUES (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `exercise_days` = VALUES(`exercise_days`)");``

Comment: Glad that my suggestion helped you solve your problem :-)

Comment: @RamRaider, is there any way to prevent the auto_increment being incremented for every ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: I believe this is just the way it is.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516958/on-duplicate-key-auto-increment-issue-mysql